# Calling The Base ServiceBase Class Methods from Overridden Methods

Tags: c#, windows-services

When implementing a Windows Service derived from `ServiceBase`, is it necessary to explicitly call base class methods such as `OnSessionChange(...)`, `OnStart(...)`, `OnStop()` or `Dispose(disposing)` inside the equivalent overridden methods? Like:

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    // our own logic
    base.OnShutdown(); // <- is this call necessary? for base.Dispose(...)? others?
}
```

I presume it should not be necessary but needed to be sure about it; especially the `Dispose` method.

Comment: It's not necessary unless you want to execute any specific business logic for each event. Dispose might be needed if you want to clean up any managed resource.

Comment: Thanks; I meant is it necessary to call base methods in our overridden methods? Not all of those might get overridden; but is those that do - are there any hidden behavior there in base methods?

Comment: None of the ServiceBase.OnXxxx() do anything.  Disposing a service never makes any sense, the service process terminates a millisecond later.  So overriding Disposing(bool) is pointless.

Comment: At `OnStop` or `OnShutdown` the `Dispose(bool disposing)` gets called. That might be important to a service that needs to do some housekeeping and cleanup for resources that need to get freed or the like.